# Summarise grouped data frame with intercept and gradient of linear model

Tags: r

I'm trying to run simple linear regressions on a grouped data frame and create a summarised data frame containing the intercept, gradient and R^2 value for each regression. I know I can collect the intercept and gradient for a single regression using `lm(formula = var1 ~ var2, data = df)$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]]` and `lm(formula = var1 ~ var2, data = df)$coefficients[["y"]]` respectively, however when I try to combine this with `summarise` I get the following error:

> Error in lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[["y"]] : subscript out of bounds

(The R^2 value calculates just fine). Here is a small reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

## Create dummy data frame
df <- tibble(treatment = factor(c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5))),
             var1 = c(1, 4, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 4, 7),
             var2 = c(2, 8, 11, 13, 4, 10, 11, 2, 6, 10)) %>%
      group_by(treatment)


reg <- df %>% 
              ## Intercept of linear model
  summarise(intercept = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]],
              ## Gradient of linear model
            gradient = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[["y"]],
              ## R^2 value of linear model
            r2 = cor(x = var1, y = var2, use = "complete.obs"))
```

How do I need to change my code to extract these values successfully for each linear model? Do I need to try a different approach entirely than using `summarise`?

Comment: Your model is not does not have a "y" term, it has a "var2" term instead.  Substitute in `coefficients[["var2"]` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Dave2e - I can't believe I spent such a long time puzzling over this when it was such a simple mistake!

Comment: you can also check out broom to keep your models and get the relevant summary statistics https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some queston regarding exactly what you want but we will assume that since the question refers to "grouped" that you want to run a separate regression for each treatment and that the regression being referred to is var1 vs. var2.  If that is not what you want please clarify the question.

1. within `group_by` dot does not refer to just the group but rather the entire data frame unless we refer to it within `do(...)`
2. always use the coef(...) function rather than `$coefficients`. Often they give the same result but not always so it is better practice to use `coef`.
3. The correlation needs to be squared to get R^2.

**1) do** Here is the pipeline:

```
df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  do({ co <- coef(lm(var1 ~ var2, .))
       summarize(., intercept = co[1], 
                    grad = co[2], 
                    r2 = cor(var1, var2, use = "complete.obs")^2)
  }) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) do/summary** We could alternately use `summary(...)$r.squared` to get R^2.

```
df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  do({ fm <- lm(var1 ~ var2, .)
       co <- coef(fm)
       summarize(., intercept = co[1], 
                    grad = co[2], 
                    r2 = summary(fm)$r.squared)
  }) %>%
  ungroup
```

**3) mulitiple lm** or we can just run the lm multiple times:

```
df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarize(intercept = coef(lm(var1 ~ var2))[1],
            grad = coef(lm(var1 ~ var2))[2],
            r2 = summary(lm(var1 ~ var2))$r.squared) %>%
  ungroup
```

**4) nlme** Also note that nlme package (which is a "recommended" package which means it is pre-installed when you install R -- you don't have to install nlme itself but only need to load it using `library`) supports lmList class:

```
library(nlme)

fm <- lmList(var1 ~ var2 | treatment, df)
cbind(coef(fm), r.squared = summary(fm)$r.squared)
```

Comment: Thank you for these alternative solutions - I've accepted this as the answer for those who want more elegant solutions to this question than my code!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the coefficients the way you did by name. Instead try this:

```r
reg <- df %>% 
              ## Intercept of linear model
  summarise(intercept = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[[1]],
              ## Gradient of linear model
            gradient = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[[2]],
              ## R^2 value of linear model
            r2 = cor(x = var1, y = var2, use = "complete.obs"))
```

Update:

It seems you simply misnamed the gradient coefficient. So while my above solution works, you could also simply substitute `var2` for `y` in your code and it works:

```r
reg <- df %>% 
              ## Intercept of linear model
  summarise(intercept = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[["(Intercept)"]],
              ## Gradient of linear model
            gradient = lm(formula = var1 ~ var2)$coefficients[["var2"]],
              ## R^2 value of linear model
            r2 = cor(x = var1, y = var2, use = "complete.obs"))
```